# List actors who were cast in more comedies than in dramas and tragedies, combined

Tags: sql, database

DATABASE Tables

- **Movie** (title, year, genre, budget, gross)
- **Director** (name, country, YofB)
- **Actor** (name, country, YofB)
- **Producer** (name, country, YofB)
- **DirectorMovie** (d_name, m_title, m_year)
- **ActorMovie** (a_name, m_title, m_year)
- **ProducerMovie** (p_name, m_title, m_year)

Attribute genre in table Movie has as value one of

```
{“comedy”, drama”, tragedy”, “musical”, “horror”}
```

Query:

```
select 
    A_NAME
from 
    ACTORMOVIE,
    (select title, GENRE 
     from movie 
     where GENRE = 'Comedy') T, 
    (select title, GENRE 
     from movie 
     where GENRE = 'drama' or  GENRE = 'tragedy') S
where 
    M_TITLE = T.title and M_TITLE = S.title
group by 
    a_name  
having 
    count(T.GENRE) > count(S.GENRE)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Hi Mian, please state clearly what your question is.

Comment: Please rephrase your exact question to reflect what you want to do in proper technical terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must join 3 tables: `Actor`, `ActorMovie` and `Movie`.
Then `group by` actor and set the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select a.name
from Actor a
inner join ActorMovie am on am.a_name = a.name
inner join Movie m on m.title = am.m_title
group by a.name
having count(case when m.genre = 'comedy' then 1 end) >
       count(case when m.genre in ('drama', 'tragedy') then 1 end)
```

The having clause could also be written:

```
having sum(case when m.genre = 'comedy' then 1 else 0 end) >
       sum(case when m.genre in ('drama', 'tragedy') then 1 else 0 end)
```

or in databases like MySql and SQLite:

```
having sum(m.genre = 'comedy') >
       sum(m.genre in ('drama', 'tragedy'))
```

You could also use this query:

```
select am.name
from ActorMovie am inner join Movie m 
on m.title = am.m_title
group by am.name
having count(case when m.genre = 'comedy' then 1 end) >
       count(case when m.genre in ('drama', 'tragedy') then 1 end)
```

in which the table `Actor` is not involved, so you join only 2 tables, because the actor's name is in the table `ActorMovie`.